# How to write hex into the text section of a binary file c#

Tags: c#

If i have a hex string such as "6C5A3003AF4668B42922879D02364878"

How do I put this into the ascii section of the binary file. I can do it manually like this:

[image: this]

But I haven't found a way to this with code, It always writes it in the hex section like this:

[image: this]

I have tried binary writer and filestream but they write it into the hex section instead

Any help would be appreciated

I actually have this stored in a byte array called Data
I have done this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <Data.Length; i++)
{
    int offset = 32 - i;

    stream.Position = allData.Length - stuff; //last 32 bytes of the file
    stream.WriteByte(Data[i]); //writes it into the hex section not text section
}
```

Comment: Just write it as a string.

Comment: Can you show the code that isn't working?

Comment: Treat it as a string not, hexadecimal values. Need some code though to be able to help you. Show us what you're doing that is not working.

Comment: Ok will do soon

Comment: Inside a .NET Assembly, strings are saved as UTF-16 strings, so `HELLO WORLD` is `H\0E\0L\0O\0 \0W\0R\0L\0D\0`. The problem can be solved, but it isn't immediate.

Comment: There is no "Hex Section". A binary file is exactly that: binary. What you _see_ in your _Hex Editor_ is a more human-friendly hex representation of the binary data. The part on the right is another interpretation of _the same data_: As (most of the time) ASCII chars. So what you probably want to do is add to the file the result of: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`

Comment: @Fildor Still in a .NET Assembly there is a ["string heap"](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-clr-metadata-1/): _#US
Also known as the user string heap, this stream stores all the strings used in code directly. All the strings you embed in your source code end up in here. This stream is only referenced from method bodies._

Comment: @xanatos I doubt OP is talking about that.

Comment: Ahhhh, now I get where you are going, @xanatos

Comment: @fierihenry I'll note that your code is wrong: `stream.Position = allData.Length - stuff`: `stuff` isn't related to `i` or to `offset`

Comment: I used Fildor's response and used Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes and added the result to the file which worked well

Comment: @GSerg I assumed OP writes binary, not as text.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I give the hex code GatewayServer(47-61-74-65-77-61-79-53-65-72-76-65-72) to the program to see how the program works

```
byte[] data = FromHex("47-61-74-65-77-61-79-53-65-72-76-65-72");
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
//write s = GatewayServer
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

convert hex data to byte data:

```
  public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
{
   hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
   byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
   for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
   {
       raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
   }
   return raw;
}
```

and for write bytes to existing file

```
 public static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
{
    //argument-checking here.
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
    {
       stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

and for write bytes to new file

```
public static void CreateFileAndWriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
{
    //argument-checking here.
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
       stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```